# pointer on a member and template parameter syntax

Tags: c++, templates

say we have a struct template taking a class , and a pointer on a member  on this class:

```
struct A<A,&A::a>
```

I can't declare template like that

```
template<class T,class U>
struct{};
```

I have to write

```
template<class T,typename T::type var>
struct{};
```

why `&A::a` can't be bind into a simple `typename T` syntax ? Before to be a pointer on a member, `&A::a` is a type so we could expect that a simple typename T works but that is not the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&A::a` is a *value*, not a *type*. So the template declaration makes no sense.

Here's how it might work:

```
template <typename A, int A::* Ptr> struct Foo { };

struct Bar { int n; };

int main()
{
    Foo<Bar, &Bar::n> f;
}
```

Or, more generally,

```
template <typename T, typename U, U T::* Ptr> struct Foo { };

Foo<Bar, int, &Bar::n> f;
```